# Finding longest common sequences in big data

Tags: linux, bigdata, data-analysis, sequencing

I have logs from a bunch (millions) of small experiments.

Each log contains a list (tens to hundreds) of entries. Each entry is a timestamp and an event ID (there are several thousands of unique event IDs, each of them may occur several times in the logs). Here is an example of the log of one experiment:

```
1403973044 alpha
1403973045 beta
1403973070 gamma
1403973070 alpha
1403973098 delta
```

I need to find sequences that are common for a number of experiments.

A sequence is several (at least two) event IDs that follow each other:

```
alpha
beta
gamma
```

Common sequence is a sequence that can be found in at least two logs. Logs

```
alpha
beta
gamma
delta
epsilon
```

and

```
iota
beta
gamma
epsilon
kappa
```

have a common sequence:

```
beta
gamma
epsilon
```

(Obviously, I'm looking for longest common sequence here.)

I am interested in large sequences that occur often. I do not know cutoff values beforehand. Say, I need top 10 (or, maybe, top 100 sequences) by length among top 1000 (or top 30%) by occurrence. (This criteria is given at random and can be changed almost arbitrarily to ease data processing.)

Any advice on how I do this in a scalable way?

I would prefer to minimize the amount of code that I have, but I would not like to use proprietary programs to get the solution.

...I think that a somewhat similar problem is solved in bioinformatics. <s>But they have much shorter alphabet than me :-)</s> Wrong! Proteomics deals with much larger alphabets! (Thanks to @JayInNyc)

Comment: I would store log files in a database first. This would be a good starting point for further analysis. A bunch of - large - text files are horribly slow to process.

Comment: I agree w/ the database approach. A tree-based approach seems appealing as well. Also, btw, proteomics has a far larger sequence space. Edit: a tree based approach does seem better to me than a db, b/c a db is cartesian while a tree is hierarchical.

Comment: Thanks for pointers! Any further keywords for me to google up?

Comment: `Any advice on how I do this in a scalable way?` and from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem: `For the general case of an arbitrary number of input sequences, the LCS problem is NP-hard.`. Is what you want NP-hard? Am I wrong or not?

Comment: @skwllsp Looks like so.

Comment: You want to detect LCS in the presence of *indel*s , which is a different problem. In DNA-matching, one would probably start by n-gram matching (and maybe later correct of the indels) Markov-chains would be nice too, but I can't think of a way to handle the indels elegantly.